# javascript animation using two pictures

Tags: javascript

I am programming animation in Javascript and got stuck. The idea is, that two pictures of diamond switch so that user see the diamond that shine. Here is my code:

```
import IMovingObject from '../interface/IMovingObject'
import AssetLoader from '../utils/AssetLoader'

export default class Diamond extends IMovingObject {
    constructor (game, x, y){
        super (game, x, y)
        this.currentAnimationState = 0
        const spriteWidth = 32
        this.animationSprites = [
            { x: 0 * spriteWidth, y: 0 * spriteWidth }
        ]
        this.FrameCount = 0
        this.fps = 30
    } 

    handleCollisionWith(obj, direction, impact) {
        this.game.post('collected', this)
        this.emit('remove', this)

        return true
    }

    draw() {
        this.game.engine.drawImage(
            this.game.assets.diamond1,
            256,
            256,
            0,
            0,
            this.x,
            this.y,
            this.width
        ) // Diamond

    }
    update(){
        this.currentAnimationState =
            (this.currentAnimationState % this.FrameCount === 0)    
    } 

}
export const isDiamond = obj => obj instanceof Diamond
```

Do anyone know what I should change on he code so that it works?

Comment: Which is your actual error?  Please, post what you've tried so far.

Comment: "I got stuck" doesn't really provide enough detail for users to help.  If you can describe exactly what the problem you're having is, you will get better results.  As alseether said, specific error messages and how they occurred will be very helpful.

Even more helpful is if you can post an actual code snippet in your question that runs and demonstrates the error or problem you are facing.

Comment: I have two pictures, that should switch - diamond1 and diamond2. When the code is written like this, which I posted, I got no error message but neither animation.